# Cannot replace original DB with modified copy

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2000

I am using Access 2000 in Windows 10 (which is probably a big no-no) and have run into a real head-scratcher.  Here is what I am trying to do:

1) Make a copy of an existing database, let's call it C:\DB\DB1.MDB

2) This database contains a table called STOOGES with three records.  The values read: LARRY, CURLY, MOE

3) DB1 was created in an old version of Access, so I have to convert the copy before modifying

4) In my converted copy, I want to change the STOOGES table so that it has a single value of SHEMP

5) Then I will delete the original DB1.MDB

6) Finally I will rename the copy to the original file name.  I haven't bothered converting it back to the old version of Access because something funny happens...

When I do this, the table STOOGES correctly shows only SHEMP after step 5.  After renaming in step 6, however, the table STOOGES mysteriously has LARRY, CURLY, MOE again.  I am dumbfounded.  After step 5 I have tried converting, compacting, saving as read-only, rebooting, shutting off my internet connection (aliens?)  No matter what I do, as soon as I rename the copy to the original filename, smart aleck Access finds a way to revert the data to the original version.  How on earth is it doing this, when there is no instance whatsoever of LARRY/CURLY/MOE in my new file?  Where in the world is it sneakily storing the original copy and then springing this nasty trap?  Any help to solve this would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Check for backup files on same dir. Not familiar with access 2000 backup restore strategy but i would check it before aliens.

Comment: Maybe Access Replication is involved?

Comment: I think you are both on the right track. The weirdness continues as I accidentally found a crucial clue last night. My file happens to be in Program Files x86 (yes I have "show hidden/protected files" enabled) so maybe Access cannot write to it. When I did a conversion, Access saved the file somewhere where Windows Explorer cannot find it...but Access sees it just fine. My best guess is that Access is saving a copy in some oddball folder somewhere, then shows the union of that folder and Program Files in the Open dialog. I'll search for it tonight. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Sure enough. It was saving a copy in my user directory, because it couldn't save directly in Program Files. Some nonsense like "appdata/local/VirtualStore/Program Files (x86)." Mystery solved.

Comment: Remember, that to Windows your database file is a document. Save it in the user's folder, say a subfolder of _%localappdata%_.